# Realized Variance in Python

Tags: python

I am still pretty new to Python, but I really want to do my analysis for my thesis in python so that I can learn more.

I am trying to estimate three types of realized variances over time in Python. Using five minute data that I have sorted out in VBA and having successfully converted the excel-dates into Python dates and matching it with the returns with the following code:

```
import xlrd as xl
import math as m
import datetime as time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


file_loc = "/Python/fivecrude.xlsx"
workbook = xl.open_workbook(file_loc)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
tot = sheet.nrows
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]

P = []
T = []
price = []
time = []

for i in range(2, tot):        
    t = data[i][0]
    ret = data[i][2]
    t = xl.xldate_as_tuple(t, 0)
    P.append(ret)
    T.append(t)

r = np.asarray(P)
time = np.asarray(T)
matrix = {'Date': time, 'Price': r}
```

Looking at Matrix I get the dates and the corresponding returns.

```
Out[466]: 
{'Date': array([[2015,    2,   27,   18,   50,    2],
        [2015,    2,   27,   18,   45,    1],
        [2015,    2,   27,   18,   40,    1],
        ..., 
        [2014,    3,    3,    8,   20,    1],
        [2014,    3,    3,    8,   15,    3],
        [2014,    3,    3,    8,   10,    3]]),
 'Price': array([ 0.00096852,  0.00226354,  0.00145784, ...,  0.00090302,
         0.00189899,  0.00135863])}
```

How can I construct a routine that will consecutively sum and square the corresponding returns for an entire day and consequently week and month? But if I can get some lead on how to do it for a day I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest version of python statistics module added that has variance and some other useful function.just use: `import statistics`